# Configuring SSL with Tomcat7 Server

Tags: java, ssl, server, tomcat7, ssl-certificate

I have a SSL Certificate (Cert1.cer file)

I created a keystore file using

```
  keytool -import -alias es-staging.cdac.in -keystore key2 -file Cert1.cer
```

I updated my server.xml with

```
        <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
     keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/key/key2"
     keystorePass="changeit" 
      sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1" 
      ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
     />
```

Then I Restarted the tomcat server

And tried to access https://52.39.134.231:8443/

My Browser(Mozilla FireFox) is showing

[image: Browser Result]

I tried to access "(Not secure) Try loading 52.39.134.231 using outdated security "

But its still redirecting me to same page

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that Firefox and Tomcat don't have a mutual cipher they could agree on. Well, there are ciphers that both Tomcat and Firefox are supporting in your case, but those have been disabled in Firefox for security reasons.

The ciphers you configured are pretty strong and restricting. Are you sure that all of them are supported by the underlying JDK version?

Comment: I have no idea about restriction of Firefox, So what should I do?

Comment: What is the JDK version you are using? Does it work if you remove the ciphers attribute from the config?
You can try the script from testssl.sh and compare the output before and after, then you should get an idea.

Comment: it doesn't work even if you remove ciphers ,error is same. using jdk 1.7 on server

Comment: Try to generate a self signed certificate and use that instead. Tomcat config looks OK.

Comment: the certificate you have is from a premium paid CA or self-signed ? If it is from a CA authority, i can tell you steps to install it without Ciphers, in an easy way .

Comment: I used both the ways, with and without the ciphers. I don't think its issued from a CA, but the url I am trying to hit ,with it ,will accept requests, because they provided it.

Comment: plz tell the steps to install it without ciphers, But it should be on server

Comment: first tell me are you using PEM encoded certificates ?

Comment: I think you can follow the guide here: http://robblake.net/post/18945733710/using-a-pem-private-key-and-ssl-certificate-with
It converts your certificates into Java Keystores and imports them.